# How can I remove the last comma from a loop in C++ in a simple way?

Tags: c++, while-loop

This program is for printing prime numbers till the input given and separating every prime number with a comma.

```
void main(){

    int N, counter=0, isPrime;

    int k, j;

    cout << "Enter maximum range: ";

    cin >> N;

    for (j=2; j<=N; j++){

        isPrime = 0;
        k = 2;

        while (k<j){

            if (j%k==0){

                isPrime++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        if (isPrime==0){

            if (k==N){
                cout << j;
            }
            else{
                cout << j << ",";
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

It is only removing the last comma for prime number inputs, not for any other input. How can I fix this?

```
Input: 23
Output: 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23
Input: 8
Output: 2,3,5,7,
Input: 9
Output: 2,3,5,7,
```

Comment: Add the comma to the previous iteration instead of to the current. Then check it's not the first iteration.

Comment: a little [helper class](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3ba6e1cf0b44dd3) if you do it often

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There is no need to `if then else` so much:

```
std::string delim = "";
for( auto&& item : vec )
{
   std::cout << delim << item;
   delim = ",";
}
```

No checking is needed for all cases, like the vector is empty or not.

If you accept an extra space in the beginning, just replace the string to char, and then the performance will be improved even more.

Answer (score 5):

Don't remove the last comma. Instead insert commas *before* each entry except the first.

Answer (score 2):

To easily remove the last comma you can use the `'\b'` character.

```
for(auto item : vec)
    std::cout << item << ", " ;
std::cout << "\b\b " << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just decide from a pre condition:

```
bool first = true;
for(j=2;j<=N;j++){
   // ...
   if(k==N) {
   if(!first) {
       cout << ',';
   }
   else {
       first = false;
   }
   cout<<j;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With minimal changes to your existing code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main()
{
    int N, counter = 0, isPrime;
    string separator = ""; // none at first
    int k, j;

    cout << "Enter maximum range: ";

    cin >> N;

    for(j = 2; j <= N; j++)
    {

        isPrime = 0;
        k = 2;

        while(k<j)
        {

            if(j%k == 0)
            {

                isPrime++;

                break; // exit while loop
            }
            k++;
        }
        if(isPrime == 0)
        {
            // if(k==N) not needed
            cout << separator << j;
            separator = ","; // comma after first
            counter++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

**Explanation**
Basically, I added a separator string which is blank at the start, i.e. the empty string, but is set to a comma for each output after the first. As such the `cout` statement will not print a comma before the first number, but will do so for each subsequent number being printed.

Comment: You might want to explain what you've changed in the original code - this would make your answer more useful to others. Thanks.

Comment: I added comments to each line I changed. I thought it was clear.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to output the first or last value manually:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int N, counter = 0;
    bool isPrime;

    cout << "Enter maximum range: ";
    cin >> N;
    if (N>=2) {
        cout << "2";
    }
    for (int j = 3; j <= N; ++j) {
        isPrime = true;
        for (int k = 2; k < sqrt(j)+1; ++k) {
            if (j % k == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) {
            cout << ", " << j;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```