# How to fill the separators between integer without the redundant one?

Tags: c++

I am trying to get the factors of positive integer. What I want is `8 = 2*2*2`. However, what I get is `*2*2*2`. How can I get ride of the first `*`? Is there a standard way to better describe this situation?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int num, i = 2;
    const char separator  = '*';
    cout << "Input a positive integer: ";
    cin >> num;
    while(num !=1){
        while((num % i) != 0){
            i++;
        }
        cout << setw(2) << setfill(separator) << i;
        num = num/i;
    }
}
```

> Input a positive integer: 8
>
> *2*2*2

Comment: The easiest way to remove something is to not add it in the first place.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove the last comma from a loop in C++ in a simple way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054983/how-can-i-remove-the-last-comma-from-a-loop-in-c-in-a-simple-way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a separator that is updated.  Start with `""` and set to `"*"` thereafter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int num, i = 2;
    const char *separator  = "";
    cout << "Input a positive integer: ";
    cin >> num;
    do {
        while((num % i) != 0){
            i++;
        }
        cout << separator << i;
        separator  = "*";
        num = num/i;
    } while (num > 1);
}
```

---

Also changed to `do` loop to cope with `num == 1` and `num == 0` which print nothing in OP's original code.  Code could use `unsigned` as a further extension/ protection.

Answer (score 0):

One way to accomplish that is by outputting setfill(separator) only when num is not equals to 1.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int num, i = 2;
    const char separator  = '*';
    cout << "Input a positive integer: ";
    cin >> num;
    while(num !=1){
        while((num % i) != 0){
            i++;
        }
        cout << setw(2) << i;
        num = num/i;
        if (num != 1)
            cout << setfill(separator);
    }
}
```